# Не закругляются углы в таблице с border

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте уважаемые гуру верстки.

Уже пару дней бьюсь над вопросом скругления краев в таблице, перерыл уже кучу статей и ничего не помогает, поэтому и обращаюсь к вам. Это календарь созданный с помощью плагина **fullcalendar.js**

Скрин:

[image: Фон вылезает за пределы скругления]

Код:

```css
.fc-unthemed .fc-content,
.fc-unthemed .fc-divider,
.fc-unthemed .fc-popover,
.fc-unthemed .fc-row,
.fc-unthemed tbody,
.fc-unthemed td,
.fc-unthemed th,
.fc-unthemed thead {
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .0625);
}

.fc-unthemed th,
.fc-unthemed td,
.fc-unthemed thead,
.fc-unthemed tbody,
.fc-unthemed .fc-divider,
.fc-unthemed .fc-row,
.fc-unthemed .fc-content,
.fc-unthemed .fc-popover,
.fc-unthemed .fc-list-view,
.fc-unthemed .fc-list-heading td {
  border-color: #ddd;
}

.fc-unthemed .fc-content,
.fc-unthemed .fc-divider,
.fc-unthemed .fc-list-heading td,
.fc-unthemed .fc-list-view,
.fc-unthemed .fc-popover,
.fc-unthemed .fc-row,
.fc-unthemed tbody,
.fc-unthemed td,
.fc-unthemed th,
.fc-unthemed thead {
  border-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div id="calendar" class="border-r fc fc-ltr fc-unthemed" style="">
  <div class="fc-view-container">
    <div class="fc-view fc-dayGridMonth-view fc-dayGrid-view" style="">
      <table class="">
        <thead class="fc-head">
          <tr>
            <td class="fc-head-container fc-widget-header">
              <div class="fc-row fc-widget-header">
                <table class="">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-mon"><span>пн</span></th>
                      <th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-tue"><span>вт</span></th>
                      <th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-wed"><span>ср</span></th>
                      <th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-thu"><span>чт</span></th>
                      <th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-fri"><span>пт</span></th>
                      <th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-sat"><span>сб</span></th>
                      <th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-sun"><span>вс</span></th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                </table>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="fc-body">
          <tr>
            <td class="fc-widget-content">
              <div class="fc-scroller fc-day-grid-container" style="overflow: hidden; height: 632px;">
                <div class="fc-day-grid">
                  <div class="fc-row fc-week fc-widget-content fc-rigid" style="height: 105px;">
                    <div class="fc-bg">
                      <table class="">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-mon fc-other-month fc-past" data-date="2019-11-25"></td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-tue fc-other-month fc-past" data-date="2019-11-26"></td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-wed fc-other-month fc-past" data-date="2019-11-27"></td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-thu fc-other-month fc-past" data-date="2019-11-28"></td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-fri fc-other-month fc-past" data-date="2019-11-29"></td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sat fc-other-month fc-past" data-date="2019-11-30"></td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sun fc-past" data-date="2019-12-01"></td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="fc-content-skeleton">
                      <table>
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <td class="fc-day-top fc-mon fc-other-month fc-past" data-date="2019-11-25"><span class="fc-day-number">25</span></td>
                            <td class="fc-day-top fc-tue fc-other-month fc-past" data-date="2019-11-26"><span class="fc-day-number">26</span></td>
                            <td class="fc-day-top fc-wed fc-other-month fc-past" data-date="2019-11-27"><span class="fc-day-number">27</span></td>
                            <td class="fc-day-top fc-thu fc-other-month fc-past" data-date="2019-11-28"><span class="fc-day-number">28</span></td>
                            <td class="fc-day-top fc-fri fc-other-month fc-past" data-date="2019-11-29"><span class="fc-day-number">29</span></td>
                            <td class="fc-day-top fc-sat fc-other-month fc-past" data-date="2019-11-30"><span class="fc-day-number">30</span></td>
                            <td class="fc-day-top fc-sun fc-past" data-date="2019-12-01"><span class="fc-day-number">1</span></td>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="fc-row fc-week fc-widget-content fc-rigid" style="height: 105px;">
                    <div class="fc-bg">
                      <table class="">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-mon fc-past" data-date="2019-12-02"></td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-tue fc-past" data-date="2019-12-03"></td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-wed fc-past" data-date="2019-12-04"></td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-thu fc-past" data-date="2019-12-05"></td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-fri fc-past" data-date="2019-12-06"></td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sat fc-past" data-date="2019-12-07"></td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sun fc-past" data-date="2019-12-08"></td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="fc-content-skeleton">
                      <table>
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <td class="fc-day-top fc-mon fc-past" data-date="2019-12-02"><span class="fc-day-number">2</span></td>
                            <td class="fc-day-top fc-tue fc-past" data-date="2019-12-03"><span class="fc-day-number">3</span></td>
                            <td class="fc-day-top fc-wed fc-past" data-date="2019-12-04"><span class="fc-day-number">4</span></td>
                            <td class="fc-day-top fc-thu fc-past" data-date="2019-12-05"><span class="fc-day-number">5</span></td>
                            <td class="fc-day-top fc-fri fc-past" data-date="2019-12-06"><span class="fc-day-number">6</span></td>
                            <td class="fc-day-top fc-sat fc-past" data-date="2019-12-07"><span class="fc-day-number">7</span></td>
                            <td class="fc-day-top fc-sun fc-past" data-date="2019-12-08"><span class="fc-day-number">8</span></td>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="fc-row fc-week fc-widget-content fc-rigid" style="height: 105px;">
                    <div class="fc-bg">
                      <table class="">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-mon fc-past" data-date="2019-12-09"></td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-tue fc-past" data-date="2019-12-10"></td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-wed fc-today " data-date="2019-12-11"></td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-thu fc-future" data-date="2019-12-12"></td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-fri fc-future" data-date="2019-12-13"></td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sat fc-future" data-date="2019-12-14"></td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sun fc-future" data-date="2019-12-15"></td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="fc-content-skeleton">
                      <table>
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <td class="fc-day-top fc-mon fc-past" data-date="2019-12-09"><span class="fc-day-number">9</span></td>
                            <td class="fc-day-top fc-tue fc-past" data-date="2019-12-10"><span class="fc-day-number">10</span></td>
                            <td class="fc-day-top fc-wed fc-today " data-date="2019-12-11"><span class="fc-day-number">11</span></td>
                            <td class="fc-day-top fc-thu fc-future" data-date="2019-12-12"><span class="fc-day-number">12</span></td>
                            <td class="fc-day-top fc-fri fc-future" data-date="2019-12-13"><span class="fc-day-number">13</span></td>
                            <td class="fc-day-top fc-sat fc-future" data-date="2019-12-14"><span class="fc-day-number">14</span></td>
                            <td class="fc-day-top fc-sun fc-future" data-date="2019-12-15"><span class="fc-day-number">15</span></td>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td class="fc-event-container">
                              <a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-end fc-draggable fc-resizable">
                                <div class="fc-content"> <span class="fc-title">Кардио</span></div>
                                <div class="fc-resizer fc-end-resizer"></div>
                              </a>
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="fc-row fc-week fc-widget-content fc-rigid" style="height: 105px;">
                    <div class="fc-bg">
                      <table class="">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-mon fc-future" data-date="2019-12-16"></td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-tue fc-future" data-date="2019-12-17"></td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-wed fc-future" data-date="2019-12-18"></td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-thu fc-future" data-date="2019-12-19"></td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-fri fc-future" data-date="2019-12-20"></td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sat fc-future" data-date="2019-12-21"></td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sun fc-future" data-date="2019-12-22"></td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="fc-content-skeleton">
                      <table>
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <td class="fc-day-top fc-mon fc-future" data-date="2019-12-16"><span class="fc-day-number">16</span></td>
                            <td class="fc-day-top fc-tue fc-future" data-date="2019-12-17"><span class="fc-day-number">17</span></td>
                            <td class="fc-day-top fc-wed fc-future" data-date="2019-12-18"><span class="fc-day-number">18</span></td>
                            <td class="fc-day-top fc-thu fc-future" data-date="2019-12-19"><span class="fc-day-number">19</span></td>
                            <td class="fc-day-top fc-fri fc-future" data-date="2019-12-20"><span class="fc-day-number">20</span></td>
                            <td class="fc-day-top fc-sat fc-future" data-date="2019-12-21"><span class="fc-day-number">21</span></td>
                            <td class="fc-day-top fc-sun fc-future" data-date="2019-12-22"><span class="fc-day-number">22</span></td>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="fc-row fc-week fc-widget-content fc-rigid" style="height: 105px;">
                    <div class="fc-bg">
                      <table class="">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-mon fc-future" data-date="2019-12-23"></td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-tue fc-future" data-date="2019-12-24"></td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-wed fc-future" data-date="2019-12-25"></td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-thu fc-future" data-date="2019-12-26"></td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-fri fc-future" data-date="2019-12-27"></td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sat fc-future" data-date="2019-12-28"></td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sun fc-future" data-date="2019-12-29"></td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="fc-content-skeleton">
                      <table>
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <td class="fc-day-top fc-mon fc-future" data-date="2019-12-23"><span class="fc-day-number">23</span></td>
                            <td class="fc-day-top fc-tue fc-future" data-date="2019-12-24"><span class="fc-day-number">24</span></td>
                            <td class="fc-day-top fc-wed fc-future" data-date="2019-12-25"><span class="fc-day-number">25</span></td>
                            <td class="fc-day-top fc-thu fc-future" data-date="2019-12-26"><span class="fc-day-number">26</span></td>
                            <td class="fc-day-top fc-fri fc-future" data-date="2019-12-27"><span class="fc-day-number">27</span></td>
                            <td class="fc-day-top fc-sat fc-future" data-date="2019-12-28"><span class="fc-day-number">28</span></td>
                            <td class="fc-day-top fc-sun fc-future" data-date="2019-12-29"><span class="fc-day-number">29</span></td>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="fc-row fc-week fc-widget-content fc-rigid" style="height: 107px;">
                    <div class="fc-bg">
                      <table class="">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-mon fc-future" data-date="2019-12-30"></td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-tue fc-future" data-date="2019-12-31"></td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-wed fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2020-01-01"></td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-thu fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2020-01-02"></td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-fri fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2020-01-03"></td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sat fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2020-01-04"></td>
                            <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sun fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2020-01-05"></td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="fc-content-skeleton">
                      <table>
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <td class="fc-day-top fc-mon fc-future" data-date="2019-12-30"><span class="fc-day-number">30</span></td>
                            <td class="fc-day-top fc-tue fc-future" data-date="2019-12-31"><span class="fc-day-number">31</span></td>
                            <td class="fc-day-top fc-wed fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2020-01-01"><span class="fc-day-number">1</span></td>
                            <td class="fc-day-top fc-thu fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2020-01-02"><span class="fc-day-number">2</span></td>
                            <td class="fc-day-top fc-fri fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2020-01-03"><span class="fc-day-number">3</span></td>
                            <td class="fc-day-top fc-sat fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2020-01-04"><span class="fc-day-number">4</span></td>
                            <td class="fc-day-top fc-sun fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2020-01-05"><span class="fc-day-number">5</span></td>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: как вы границу задаёте? стили покажите ваши

Comment: Добавил стили .

Comment: @HamSter, но это будет работать, только если таблице не задан border-collapse: collapse. А если нужны ещё границы в ячейках?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32372122/how-to-round-the-corners-of-the-fullcalendar-jquery-plugin

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32372122/how-to-round-the-corners-of-the-fullcalendar-jquery-plugin

Comment: @HamSter ссылки не совсем относятся к моей проблеме, да там есть закругление, но там не показана реальная проблема, да и не помогает если честно, очень странно

Comment: Добавляете обертке, например, `fc-view-container   {  border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ddd; }` а у внутренних блоков (td th) убираете border соответствующие (top, left ...)